# Error: "Cannot index into null array"

Tags: list, powershell

I am getting this error while trying to get the list name

```
Cannot index into a null array.
+       $clientlist = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"];
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `$web` is properly set? As in what happens if you run `$web.Lists` or even `$web.Title`?

Comment: please paste your code where you are setting $web

Comment: `$webNew=Get-Spweb $web
    $clientlist = $webNew.Lists["Shared Documents"]`